# How do I look up grant information of PIs in Germany?

Tags: funding, germany, databases

I know NIH allows you to look up grant information of PIs in the United States. Is there a similar website in Germany (DFG?) that allows you to see grants information of PIs?

Also if someone knows of a similar website in Sweden?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can find DFG-funded projects on their website via the [DFG GEPRIS](http://http:/http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/OCTOPUS?context=projekt&index=0&task=showSearchSimple) tool. This only shows the DFG funded projects, for other projects the PI might be involved in, you should check the websites of the respective funding agencies (e.g. [CORDIS](http://cordis.europa.eu/projects/home_en.html) for those funded by the EU).